# How to change the visibility of markers on Google Map using Cluster Manager? (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a simple app that show a lot of markers on a map (Google Map). At the moment I have over 3,000 markers and this number keeps growing as the database gets bigger.

I also have a few checkboxes that dictate which markers are to be shown, vice versa.

Originally I was adding each marker like this (inside a loop going through every location)

```
Marker marker;
marker = mMap.addMarker (markerOptions);
mMarkerArrayList.add(marker);
```

Then when the user interacted with the checkboxes, I simply made markers visible/invisible. This is faster removing, and re-adding the markers.
The code in the Checkbox Change Listener was something like this:

```
for (Marker marker : mMarkerArrayList) {
    if (condition) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

And then make the visible again on another change of the checkbox.

However, adding all these markers individually in the beginning was taking a long time (1-2 seconds) and as the markers can only be added in the UI thread, it was freezing the UI (including my progress bar) for that amount of time.

After a lot of research, and not getting anywhere, the only thing I could do was add the markers using the ClusterManager (android-maps-utils library). This loads twice as fast, and does not block my UI.
Adding code is something like this (here myLocation is the object of my MyLocation class which holds the lcoation and relevant data for each point).

```
for (MyLocation myLocation : mMyLocationArrayList) {
    mClusterManager.addItem(myLocation)
}
```

Now the issue is linking the checkboxes to these ClusterItem objects. I cannot find any method, or field in the library to change the visibility of these markers (ClusterItem). In the previous method (changing the visibility) was almost instantaneous (fast enough that the user would not feel any lag). However, now, I need to add and remove these markers everytime, and there is a lag, and it is very obvious to the user.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers()` in order to get the Marker collection, and then hide certain Markers in the same way as you were before:

```
Collection<Marker> markerCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers();

for (Marker marker : markerCollection) {
    if (condition) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great!
I still have one more little detail which this one does not cover (and it has to do with the way the library is setup). It removes the markers all fine, but if the zoom is out (meaning there are clusters), since the clusters are not markers at that point, the clusters remain. Is there a way to also incorporate removing those Clusters (or better adjusting their members so it also reflects the new count)? Thanks again

Comment: @Khash Did you found a solution for that problem?

Comment: @D.Roters Not really, at the time I ended up abandoning the cluster and reverted back into the previous version (adding markers and keeping them in an ArrayList and then manipulate individual markers' visibility). This was a bit unfortunate that I was not able to Clusters the way I wanted. That being said, the project have been on an auto-pilot for the past year as I was busy with other work so I did not necessarily revisit this. I am planning on updating the whole project in the next few months, so if you do have a suggestion, I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

@Khash  I have had some success with the following code (i.e. hides both the Markers and Clusters), although I experience a similar issue when I zoom the map in or out the Markers and Clusters re-appear.
Hope this helps, happy coding!

```
if (hide) {
    /* Hide all Markers and Clusters */
    mMyClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().hideAll();
    mMyClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().hideAll();
} else {
    /* Show all Markers and Clusters */
    mMyClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().showAll();
    mMyClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().showAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

I have a simple solution. Add a boolean isVisible to your renderer class like this :

```
class MyRenderer(
    private val context: Context,
    map: GoogleMap,
    clusterManager: ClusterManager<MyPost>
) : DefaultClusterRenderer<MyPost>(context, map, clusterManager) {

    //Make sure it's public
    var isVisible: Boolean = true
   

    /**
     * Method called before the cluster item (the marker) is rendered.
     * This is where marker options should be set.
     */
    override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(
        item: MyPost,
        markerOptions: MarkerOptions
    ) {
        markerOptions
            .visible(isVisible)
            //add your other options
    }

    override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(
        cluster: Cluster<MyPost>,
        markerOptions: MarkerOptions
    ) {
        markerOptions.visible(isVisible)
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions)
    }

    // ...

}
```

And next, based on the code of @GeNextAppLabs, set the renderer variable to true or false :

```
if (hide) {
    /* Hide all Markers and Clusters */
    mMyClusterManager.markerCollection.hideAll()
    mMyClusterManager.clusterMarkerCollection.hideAll()
    (mMyClusterManager.renderer as? MyRenderer)?.isVisible = false
} else {
    /* Show all Markers and Clusters */
    mMyClusterManager.markerCollection.showAll()
    mMyClusterManager.clusterMarkerCollection.showAll()
    (mMyClusterManager.renderer as? MyRenderer)?.isVisible = true
}
```

Now you can zoom in or zoom out, the markers won't show up until you set isVisible to true !

This code works for me, enjoy :)